# How to use oData service?

Tags: javascript, odata

Recently I have heared about the microsoft oData.

Now I have a url like http://sitename.com/Nomad/ApplicationData.svc with access(user and pass).

I am expecting some destination result as json format.

I have downloaded the query-builder and applied like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/datajs-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/odata-query-builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Document ready event handler.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var createdQueryBuilder = new OData.explorer.DataExplorer(
            {
                // An array containing the different endpoints.
                endpoints: [
                    {
                        name: 'OData',
                        url: 'http://sitename.com/Nomad/ApplicationData.svc',
                    }
                ]
            });
    });
</script>
```

But not getting any proper data result, am I going to the right way? Can somebody provide some simple reference for implement the oData service.

Comment: Got error status like this "{\"message\":\"HTTP request failed\",\"request\":{\"requestUri\":\"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some odata service samples: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/.